# Using Spacy in Turkish

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am making an personal assistant with python. I decided to use spaCy to get proper nouns in sentences like names or things like that. I live in Turkey. I found alpha version of Turkish. I imported it like that.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('tr')
doc = nlp(u'Ben Akın.') #It means 'I am Akın.'
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

I get output like this.

```
[]
```

Also when I use English

```
import spacy
spacy.load('en')
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp('I am Akın')
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

Output is like

```
[('Akın', 'PERSON')]
```

Can you help?

Comment: Try `nlp = spacy.load('xx')`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I got `[('Ben Akın', 'PER')]`. First, what is PER(_I think it means Person_), Second, It classifies the sentence. I need to get just name.

Comment: have you imported `xx_ent_wiki_sm` instead of `en_core_web_sm`

Comment: Yes. I need to get just name(_Akın_) to remember it as person's name but it returns the sentence

Comment: I used `doc = nlp(u"Benim adım Akın ve Google da çalışıyorum.")`(_Means "My name is Akın and I work at Google."_) and I got `[('Akın', 'PER') , ('Google', 'ORG')]` but when i use `doc = nlp(u"Ben Akın ve Google da çalışıyorum.")`(_Means "I am Akın and I work at Google."_) I got `[('Ben Akın', 'PER'), (Google, 'ORG')]`

Comment: In other languages the packages implemented doesn't give 100% results!! Still, I think you get good one!! Try out with multiple sentences and check

Comment: Is there any way I can make the other ones work? (_Like "Ben Akın ve Google da çalışıyorum_" above)

Comment: I dont understand!! I guess both the statements are giving you correct answers!!

Comment: they give but second one gives 'Ben Akın' I need just 'Akın' to get just name

Comment: I don't think so it can work that way!! This would be the best you can get!!

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
import xx_ent_wiki_sm
nlp = spacy.load('xx')
```

Comment: As I said it gives `Ben Akın` as output _**sometimes**_. I just need `Akın`. Because I just need name. For instance; It will say Hello after getting name. But name should be `Akın`. When it's `Ben Akın` It would be like `Hello Ben Akın`